# CKEditor Link plugin add a style to rendered element

Tags: attributes, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I am trying to add the following attribute to the  element that is created once I hit OK in the link plugin dialog

```
style="color:#1cb9b0"
```

Not to sure where I would add the attribute would it be in the onOk function? that is currently

```
        onOk: function () {
            var data = {};

            // Collect data from fields.
            this.commitContent(data);

            if (!this._.selectedElements.length) {
                insertLinksIntoSelection(editor, data);
            } else {
                editLinksInSelection(editor, this._.selectedElements, data);

                delete this._.selectedElements;
            }
        },
```

Any tips or hints would be awesome.

Comment: after some checking looks like i need to apply the change in the **insertLinksIntoSelection** and **editLinksInSelection** functions that seem to set the element up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So was right in suggesting that when inserting or editing an existing link that I can just add the style attribute there.

Inside the `insertLinksIntoSelection` and `editLinksInSelection` functions I added the following line

```
attributes.set.style = "color: #1cb9b0;"; // add style attribute
```

Worked perfectly.